# Why is my toaster notification not working properly in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, toast

Using `ajax` I am updating some value and in response I am showing `toaster` red (for error) and green (for success) but problem is that if there is error it always shows green toaster. I want a red toaster on error here is my code which I already tried

js

```
success: function (data) {
    toastr.success(data.message);
},
    error: function(err) {
    toastr.error(err.message);
}
```

controller

```
if (some condition){ 
    $customer->save();
    return response()->json([
        'success'=> true
        'message' => 'User status updated successfully.'
    ]);
} else {
    return response()->json([
        'error'=> true,
        'message'=> 'Visit Failed distance is too long'
    ]);
    // this should be red toast but it green
}
```

Please read comment on above code `// this should be red toast but it green`can someone help me how I can show red toaster on error?

Comment: you probably want to return the response with some status code that does not imply success for your error path as without setting a response code you are getting a 20x response, success

Comment: Your `error` function up top is never called in the first place, since your server is always sending back a regular reply and the ajax request has therefore succeeded. You can either check `data.success` in your `success` callback and proceed accordingly, or return a laravel response that will trigger the `error` callback like lagbox suggests.

Comment: The title of this question s not very searchable.

Comment: thanx for all contributor i am new to ajax and your information is helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**success:** The success function is called if the Ajax request is completed successfully. i.e. If the server returns a **HTTP** status of **200** OK.

**error:**  The error function is executed if the server responds with a **HTTP** error. So if you get an error, then `err.message` will be undefiend here. So put a custom message instead :

```js
success: function (data) {
     if(data.success == true){
           toastr.success(data.message);
     } else {
           toastr.error(err.message);
     }
},
error: function(err){
     // Your Error Message
     toastr.error("Error with AJAX callback !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First install this one

> composer require yoeunes/toastr

, then add

> toastr()->error('Oops! Something went wrong!');
> please try it...happy coder..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).